# MediaPlayer.isPlaying returning true even after MediaPlayer.OnCompleteListener has been called

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am running a MediaPlayer instance for audio playback from inside a Service. I have implemented `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` in my service and I am sending a local broadcast action to notify my activity that the playback is complete inside the implemented `onCompletion`. On receiving the broadcast, I am checking the value returned MediaPlayer.isPlaying and it returns **true**. Is this some bug or the behavior is normal as the two things might mean different things.